# Rollback Riak node leaving ring job

Tags: riak

I have run riak-admin cluster leave riak@gcp-07-internal.com on a node I want to leave riak ring.
The command runs successfully but the partitions transfer is taking more than 2 days.

```
riak@gcp-07  =======>  media-riak@gcp-01
-internal.com                  -internal.com      
      |=============================================  | 106%  
                          16.96 MB/s
```

Is there a way to accelerate this process? If not, I'd line to cancel this process and keep the node back in the ring.

I'm running on riak_kv_version 2.1.7 and all my buckets have n_val=3. How can I safely kill this job

I tried to force join command but had an error message: node already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patrick,

Thanks for your inquiry. Backing out of a node removal generally requires downtime and is not exactly a refined process. As such, I would avoid it at all costs.

If you want to speed things up, I would suggest increasing your transfer limit as far as you deem safe or up to the maximum accepted 8 e.g. `riak-admin transfer-limit 8` which will allow even more transfers to happen in parallel. Please note that this will cause increased load across the cluster, so, if your cluster is already under heavy load, this is not advisible. In such a situation, I would recommend patience.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, what is the maximum value allowed for transfer-limit?

Comment: Unless you do some behind-the-scenes skullduggery in `riak attach`, it is 8 as mentioned above.

Comment: Here is the output of `riak attach`: Erlang R16B03-1 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]. does that mean 10 is my limit? **async-threads:10**

Comment: The `riak-admin transfer-limit` command maximum limit is 8 and this has nothing to do with async-threads. If you try to set `riak-admin transfer-limit` higher than 8 then it will max out at 8.
As you seem to have a lot of Riak related questions, you might like to join the Post-Riak community at 
https://join.slack.com/t/postriak/shared_invite/zt-1ttgxs0ya-0LaKNLdcPMH_0URcMwl6Dg where you can ask questions not only to me but also to the rest of the open-source community who continue develop and upkeep Riak.